# Publish JAR file(.EXE) on Windows Store

Tags: java, file, jar

I have a App coding in Java, I take the .JAR file and I convert it into .EXE(windows). I want to know if it possible to publish it on Windows Store. May someone help me please?

Comment: You can only publish UWP (Universal Windows Platform) apps in the Windows Store.

Comment: Check [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/publish/upload-app-packages)

Comment: Ohh Jesus, Why Windows does that. Thx you @Habil